# how to get RSS data when multiple item with same name

Tags: php, parsing, rss

I want to parse an existing RSS feed from another website with php but i'm facing some troubles.

```
<pubDate>Wed, 10 Dec 2014 18:49:07 +0000</pubDate>
<dc:creator>
<![CDATA[ Myself ]]>
</dc:creator>
<category>
<![CDATA[ News ]]>
</category>
<category>
<![CDATA[ Transport ]]>
</category>
```

etc...

I use different ways but i'm still unable to read more than the first 'category'. I would like to be able to check if there is more than one 'category' and be able to read all of them in that case.

Thanks to all

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: You can see it below. I added it.

Comment: Put the code in your question, not as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for an unknown amount of `<category>` tags like so:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath("/category") as $category)
{
    // Do something
}
```

This answer assumes that you're using PHP's [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Additionally, if you want to know if there is more than one category:

```
count($xml->xpath("/category")) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string =
"<"."?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?".">
<girls>
   <girl>
  <name>Alice</name>
  <eyes>Blue</eyes>
  <hair>Brown</hair>
  <nice>Yes</nice>
  <category>Not</category>
</girl>
<girl>
  <name>Betty</name>
  <eyes>Brown</eyes>
  <hair>Black</hair>
  <nice>Yes</nice>
  <category>Not</category>
</girl>
<girl>
  <name>Candace</name>
  <eyes>Blue</eyes>
  <hair>Blonde</hair>
  <nice>No</nice>
  <category>Hot</category>
</girl>
<girl>
  <name>Danielle</name>
  <eyes>Green</eyes>
  <hair>Blonde</hair>
  <nice>Yes</nice>
  <category>Hot</category>
</girl>
```

";

```
$x = new DOMDocument();
$x->loadXML($string);
$hot_or_not = $x->getElementsByTagName("category");

foreach ($hot_or_not as $a) {
    echo $a->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: You might need to flesh out your answer with some explanantion or detail

Comment: Tried that but that won't work at all. $category still 'null'